# Automatically resize windows when new windows are opened

Tags: appearance

I want my desktop to automatically resize all the windows I have open. So If I have one window open and open a second then the windows will be shown side by side and if a third one is opened then it will divide them so 1 window is on the left half, the second in the top right and the third in the bottom right. This way you can always see all your open windows. I understand this would get messy quickly if too many are opened but most of the time it would be fine.

Failing this just a system that always has the desktop divided into 4.

I often run my system will a lot of terminals so this would be really useful. I've also seen other devs have a system like this but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [tiling window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager)

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what a tiling window manager, such as i3, does.

Comment: See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/install-regolith-linux-i3-gaps-ubuntu for info about a new Ubuntu based distro that comes with i3.